# Text message notification- vibration during call

Tags: 7.0-nougat, vibration, motorola-moto-g-4g

I am on Moto G4+ with Android N, version 7.0.

I am facing a weird issue where any incoming text message causes the phone to vibrate **even when I am in the middle of a phone call.**

Is there a standard first party way to turn this behaviour off? This is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

Go to **Settings > Sound and vibration >** uncheck **Also vibrate for call** box.

If that does not work, try just disabling the vibration at all (Which is not what you seem to want)

Go to **Settings > SMS > Notifications > Vibrate off**

Comment: This turns off vibration for calls also.

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be:

Go to your dialer, then open **settings** and unselect the **notify during calls** options.

Comment: Couldn't find the said option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use message+.. open up message+ like you're going to send a text, open the menu (the 3 lines in the upper left corner), touch settings, go to the bottom and touch advance, then uncheck 'notification during call'

Answer (score -2):

It's a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37117327) in 7.0.  And very annoying.